# Automatic Column Update Between Two Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I hope you're doing well. This is my first time asking a question here, and I'm really grateful for any help I can get. I'll try to explain my situation as clearly as possible.

I have two tables in my database: "pole" and "marque." The "pole" table consists of two columns: "id_pole" and "pole_name." Meanwhile, the "marque" table has several columns, but I'll focus on just two: "id_pole" and "name_pole."

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: Whenever I update a column in the "marque" table, I want the corresponding value in the "pole" table to automatically update. To illustrate, in the "pole" table, I have two rows:

1. id_pole: 1, pole_name: office
2. id_pole: 2, pole_name: graphique

In the "marque" table, I currently have:

id_pole: 1, name_pole: office

What I want to happen is, if I modify a value in the "marque" table (let's say I change "name_pole" to "graphique"), I want the database to automatically update the value of "id_pole" to 2, based on the information in the "pole" table.

Thank you so much for your time and assistance!

I've tried using triggers, but I've run into some challenges. If anyone has insights or suggestions on how to accomplish this effectively, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance.

here is the script that i've used :

```
`DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_name_pole_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON marque
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.id_pole != OLD.id_pole THEN
    UPDATE marque
    SET name_pole = (SELECT pole_name FROM pole WHERE id_pole = 
NEW.id_pole)
    WHERE id_marque = NEW.id_marque;
END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_id_pole_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON marque
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.name_pole != OLD.name_pole THEN
    UPDATE marque
    SET id_pole = (SELECT id_pole FROM pole WHERE pole_name = NEW.name_pole)
    WHERE id_marque = NEW.id_marque;
END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;`
```

Comment: In AFTER UPDATE trigger you cannot alter the data in this table. I.e. `CREATE TRIGGER .. AFTER UPDATE ON marque .. UPDATE marque ..` is not allowed. You must use ``SET NEW.id_pole = ..`` in BEFORE UPDATE trigger.